# Quantum entanglement of 3

Tags: quantum-entanglement

Could there be 3 particles (instead of only 2 particles) that could be connected by same quantum entanglement (like minus, plus and "some third position")?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

For example, the Greene-Hornberg-Zeiliger (GHZ) state (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenberger%E2%80%93Horne%E2%80%93Zeilinger_state), which is important in quantum information theory, is an $N$-particle entangled state:

$$|GHZ\rangle=\frac{|000...0\rangle+|111...1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$$

In this case, whenever you measure one particle, you know the state of all the others. Note that this is **not** always the case; for example, in the maximally-entangled 3-qubit state:

$$|\psi\rangle=\frac{|100\rangle+|010\rangle+|001\rangle}{\sqrt{3}}$$

If you measure one qubit as being in state $|1\rangle$, then the other two qubits are in state $|0\rangle$, but if you measure that qubit as being in state $|0\rangle$, then the other qubits are still entangled, being in the state $\frac{|01\rangle+|10\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty cool. Thanks!